# Why Regular Expression test give different result on same word?

Tags: javascript, regex, boolean

I am doing challenges in freecodecamp and doing some of my code here:
[No Repeats](https://repl.it/Hpuk/1)

```js
var arr = [ 'aab', 'aab', 'baa', 'baa', 'aba', 'aba', 'baa' ];

function remove(arai){
  var repeatRegex = /(.)\1{1,}/gi;
  var result = [];
  
  console.log(arai[0],repeatRegex.test(arai[0]));
  console.log(arai[1],repeatRegex.test(arai[1]));
  console.log(arai[2],repeatRegex.test(arai[2]));
  console.log(arai[3],repeatRegex.test(arai[3]));
  console.log(arai[4],repeatRegex.test(arai[4]));
  console.log(arai[5],repeatRegex.test(arai[5]));
}

remove(arr);
```

But it turn out that same word resulting in different boolean value.
could anybody explain this to me?
Thank you very much.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/t14yVC/1

Comment: documentation states that `called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Comment: ... try removing the `g` flag

Comment: @Phil thanks, i try it and it work fine.